# Matplotlib & Tkinter: prevent titles from hiding the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, subplot

I have two subplots, each with title. I plot them below with tkinter. 
That works the way it should. My problem is that while decreasing the whole window the title of the lower plot covers the x-label of the upper plot. Is there a possibility to have a minimum space between the subplot(-titles)? Thanks :)

here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk()
x = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
y_2 = [9, 6, 3, 1, 4, 7, 6, 2, 2]

fig = Figure(figsize=(9, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.set_title("TITLE ONE")
ax.set_ylabel("Y1")
ax.set_xlabel("X")
line = ax.plot(x, y_1, color="black" )[0]

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title("TITLE TWO")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y2")
ax2.set_xlabel("X")
ax2.plot(x, y_2, color="black")
fig.tight_layout()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Full window - perfect plot]
[image: smaller window - not perfect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `fig.tight_layout()` line, and instead use

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True
```

on top of your script.

Comment: Or use constrained_layout: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html